# How to handle panic situations when user minimizes an app during a long running task such as an api call?

Tags: android, api, kotlin, asynchronous

If a user minimizes an android app during a long running task such as login or sign in operation or any such api call, how to manage or handle the state of the app in such situations ?

Answer (score 0):

You can read all about how to handle state changes [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/state-changes).

For handling long-running tasks, like authentication or API calls, [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/background) is a good starting point.

Anything more specific, just update your question and maybe someone can help.